# BSoD on vagrant up (KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED) - Windows 8

Tags: laravel-5, vagrant, homestead, vagrant-windows

I have a problem with `Vagrant`, trying to initialize a `virtualbox` with `laravel/homestead` box.

I have installed latest version of `Vagrant (1.7.4)` on my Windows 8 OS.
I have installed Oracle VirtualBox 5.5.0.

Then I did this in windows Command Prompt:

`vagrant add box laravel/homestead` to add the laravel homestead box

`vagrant init laravel/homestead`

and

`vagrant up`

After `vagrant up` somewhere in the process the system fails with BSoD (KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED)

Any ideas of what i could have done wrong, or have anybody experienced this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: It your Windows 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: @D-side My windows 8 is on 64-bit

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you don't have Hyper-V windows resource active.
If you had installed Docker before check this, coz Docker needs Hyper-V.

In my case this works for me

Search for "Windows resource" on your windows start menu, and click on Enable or Disable windows resources, find Hyper-V, uncheck all checkboxes and OK. Restart your machine after this.

Ty

Answer (score 0):

I had almost same issue(BSOD gave error SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION). 
Yesterday I installed Docker on Windows 10 and today I tried to "vagrant up"(using VirtualBox Provisioner) and got the BSOD. Hyper-V was conflicting and I turned it off from "Windows Features" and the issue got resolved.